# Как запретить повторную отправку формы?

Tags: php, форма

Есть функция, которая выводит форму для добавления фото в каталог с выводом  на экран. Беда в том, что если после добавления фото обновить страницу, то фотография добавиться еще раз, и еще  и еще, потому что каждый раз отправляется форма. Как это пресечь?

Comment: Делайте редирект на данную страницу сразу после заливки видео) и тогда обновление не будет приводить к повторной отправке формы

Comment: Спасибо, будем разбираться. А вот еще вопросик. На странице, допустим    
  http://mysite.php?view=main&id=12  
есть ссылка <a href=...> Как в ней прописать href, чтобы она ссылалась на эту же страницу с этими же параметрами view=main&id=12? 
Пробовал $_SERVER[PHP_SELF] и т.д., но при этом теряются все параметры адресной строки

Comment: возможные параметры известны? добавтье их в ручную 
`if(isset($_GET['id'])) $url.="&id=".$_GET['id']//и т.д.`

Comment: Так я и думал.
А вот с редиректом не получается. Форма с фото обрабатывается этой же страницей.

Comment: редирект на эту же страницу сделать можно) и если это не перманентный редирект то данные не отправятся.(точно не помню тип редиректа, который просто переходит по ссылке без отправки данных) кроме редиректа есть вариант со скрытым полем. Храним в базе некое значение, и выдаем пользователю его скрытым полем, при заливке файла, удаляем из базы этот ключек, при добавлении файла проверяем есть ли в базе ключ переданный пользователем. если нет - ничего с файлом не делаем, если есть сохраняем

Comment: Туплю.
<?
if (isset($_POST[something])) {
  ... doing something
}
?>
<form method=POST>
  <input type='file' name='file'>
  <input type='submit' name='something' value='sub'>
</form>
 А куда здесь влепить редирект?

Comment: { ... doing something {do redirect}} как только сделали что хотели с данными делаем редирект) получаем очистку формы у пользователя) и пользователь видет то что залил)

Comment: в пхп адреса с параметрами $url собираете с `$_SERVER-a,(REQUEST_URI,QUERY_STRING,etc)`, потом перенаправляете с `header("Location: $url");` Правда, если до этой строчки есть выводимое контент, то буферизуйте.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть старый добрый костыль - уникальный ключ в каждой форме.

Как это работает. В каждой генеренной форме есть поле типа

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo(rand(10000,99999));?>" />
```

В скрипте вы проверяете:

```
if ($_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['lastToken'])
{
    вывод сообщения об ошибке
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['lastToken'] = $_POST['token'];
    обработка формы

}
```

Решение немного корявое, но задача не настолько требовательна, чтоб нужно было больше.

Comment: Ваш код работать не будет) там ошибка.

Comment: @ToRcH565 Простите - где?

Comment: Да с самого начала.

>if ($_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['lastToken'])

**Что если POST вообще не отправляли?**

> if ( isset($_POST['token'])) // тогда возможно

Comment: Ваш вариант
    if ($_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['lastToken'])
    {
        вывод сообщения об ошибке
    }

Верный вариант

    if ($_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['lastToken'])
    {
        Обработка кода
    }

Для наглядности не добавлял проверку на установленность токена, да и без нее пхп ошибки выдать не должен(хотя не уверен), но работать будет не корректно.

Comment: Про проверку на наличие поля в запросе - согласен - это не корректно. Хотя именно в данном случае оно отработает и без него.

Насчет условия - все верно - ошибкой является только наличие двух одинаковых ключей в ПОСТах подряд. Мы говорим о защите от случайного повторного клика.

Это в неумелых руках гораздо надежнее, чем полноценная защита от левых запросов - генерировать соль, писать в сессию, потом сверять её, а потом начинает не сходится))

Answer (score 1):

После обработки формы, выполнить

```
header("Location:".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

если возникнет ошибка

> headers were already sent

в самом верху Вашего документа напишите

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос решен 4 года назад...

Answer (score -1):

Через `if(isset($_GET['foto'])) exit;` нельзя, или я что неправильно понял? ???

Comment: Неверно поняли, если отправить какие либо данные браузером, а после обновить страницу - данные отправляются повторно(т.е. как в вашем примере переменная $_GET['foto'] будет содержать данные)